# TSQL grouping and number of rows by order

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the following parameters seq_num - Identity column, serial - serial number for the machine, UniqueVPD - a combination of serial number and time, and time for the auction run time.

I am tryting to create a tsql script that will group the rows with the same serial and different UniqueVPD, and will number them from the one with the earliest date and/or earliest date to the latest one, so for example in the sample table provided, the rows will be numbered from 1 to 5

[image]

Comment: Go ahead and try. Then post your code and data (as text, not images) and explain what you're having trouble with. Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Row_Number` window function

```
select Num = Row_number()Over(Partition by serial order by [time]), *
from yourtable
```

to update,

```
with cte as 
(
select Num = Row_number()Over(Partition by serial order by [time]), *
from yourtable
)
update cte set Numberofruns = Num
```

Comment: Thanks!!! This is giving me the correct answer. I have tried to update the row numbers by an inner join of the.                                                        update a set a.[NumberOfRuns]=b.num
from table1 as a
inner join
(select num=row_number() over (Partition by serial order by [time]),*
  from [table1]) as b
on a.serial=b.serial   however I get the wrong num in the update (And the correct in the select), any ideas on what can cause it?

Comment: That works, thanks again. I have marked your code as the answer. I also voted It up.

Comment: @Jim D I don't think you have enough reputation to vote up ;)